# Example circumference metric space non complete

Tags: metric-spaces

I am asked to show using an example that space [image]

where [image]

is not a complete space.

I know the circumference is complete, but I don't understand why the other part makes it non complete.

Comment: What do you mean by "circumference"? It seems like a linguistic translation error.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can find a sequnce which approximates a discontinuous function.

You can define a sequence of continuous functions which approximate $1_{[\frac{1}{2},2]}(x)$.

For example, $f_n(x)=(x+\frac{1}{2})^n1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(x)+1_{(\frac{1}{2},1]}$.

Comment: And how can i do that :(